# Using Windows Mobile Hotspot and WSL2 or WSA at the same time

Tags: wsl2, mobile-hotspot

I'm running WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows (10.0.22000.527).  My WSL2 kernel is at 5.10.16.

When I open Windows Mobile Hotspot, WSL can no longer connect to the network. After stopping the Hotspot, the WSL networks work again.

Is there a way to have the WSL2 network functional while Windows Hotspot is active?

I've tried my best to find a solution, but I haven't been successful so far.